# Adding entire array to nsdictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

```
NSDictionary *searchResponseJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];

arrayOfRestaurants = searchResponseJSON[@"businesses"];

NSDictionary *businesses = [arrayOfRestaurants firstObject];

NSString *businessesID = businesses[@"id"];
```

I'm trying to get all the data from the array into the nsdictionary instead of just the first object.  Is there a better way to do this?  I cant seem to be able to get all the data from the array into the nsdictionary

Side note: I'm very new to Objective c

Comment: do you want to create a dictionary with key and value being same for each object in the array ? Also what does arrayOfRestaurants hold ? array of objects or array of dictionaries ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri To you second Q "array of objects or array of dictionaries ?": Since it is a JSON, "objects" *are* dictionaries.

Comment: However, I have the same Q: do you want to have a dictionary of the form id->data?

Comment: thnx for clarification @AminNegm-Awad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *dictProducts=[response valueForKey:kViewModel];
```

Add object to Array

```
 [_yourArray addObject:[dictProducts objectForKey:kProductID]];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dict setObject: _yourArray forKey:@"Your_Key"];
```

You can use this dictionary in this class using same key

Answer (score 0):

Just use a for loop iterate on array and you will get each object from there and do your stuff.i don't what you need after you get all the objects just tell me and i will edit my answer

```
 NSDictionary *searchResponseJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
    if [searchResponseJSON[@"businesses"] isKindofClass: [NSDictionary class]] {
    arrayOfRestaurants = dictionary;

    for NSDictionary * dictionary in arrayOfRestaurants {
    print("dictionary")
    }
```

}

Comment: arrayOfRestaurants may or may not contain a dictionary. If it doesnt contain a dictionary, your code will crash!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one Its may be helpful to you

```
 NSArray * myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"hello", @"hi", @"hey"];

 NSDictionary * dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:myArray forKey:@"threeLetters"];

 NSMutableDictionary * mutableDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:10];
 [mutableDict setObject:myArray forKey:@"threeLetters"];
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSDictionary` is an `unordered collection of objects` but each containing  value is `associated with a key,` which acts like a label for the value.

NSArray * array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One",@"Two"@"Three",@"Four",nil];

1) insert array elements directly as shown below:

```
[NSDictionary initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One",@"Two"@"Three",@"Four",nil], @"FirstKey", nil];
```

2) insert NSArray in NSDictionary

```
NSDictionary * dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:myArray forKey:@"FirstKey"];
```